# Azure Devops Backlog Prioritizing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, backlog

Is there any chance to drag and drop Backlog Items like in Jira to change order in Backlog in Azure Devops? THX

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Boards -> Backlog` and make sure you have no filters enabled. You can then drag and drop single or multiple items up and down in the list.

[image: Backlog view in Azure DevOps]

It is also possible to rearrange the order in the board under `boards -> boards` through drag and drop. It is also possible to rearrange the order from the `Sprints` view.

A [Basic license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels) is required to access full capabilities of Azure Boards. Users with Stakeholder access level can only update the state of the items on the board (i.e which columns they appear in) and can thus not rearrange the order.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer! do you know whether this action requires admin permissions? I`m asking because I can`t do this... Do you know whether it`s possible to rearrange the order in sprint backlog? thanks a lot!

Comment: You need "Basic" access level to unlock all features under Boards, my best guess is that you only have "Stakeholder" at the moment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels